# Matrix inversion using woodbury indentity inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, regression

Consider closed-form solution of linear regression $$ \hat{\beta}=\left(\lambda I+X^TX\right)^{-1}X^Ty $$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Say we have extra data points $(X_{n+1}, y_{n+1})$.  We can define \begin{gather*}
X' = (\frac{X}{x_n+1}) \in \mathbb{R^{(n+1)\times d}} \\
y' = (\frac{t}{y_n+1}) \in \mathbb{R^{(n+1)}}
\end{gather*} and compute $$\hat{\beta'}=\left(\lambda I+X'^TX'\right)^{-1}X'^Ty'$$

Let \begin{gather*}
V_{n} = X^{T}X+\lambda I \\
V_{n+1} = X'^{T}X'+\lambda I
\end{gather*}  How to derive $V_{n+1}^{-1}$ as a function of $V_{n}^{-1}$ using Woodbury matrix identity?

Answer (score 1):

$X^TX=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^Tx_i$, where each $x_i$ is row $i$ within $X$ (with $x_i$ a row vector, $x_i^T$ a column vector).  Therefore,
$X'^TX'=X^TX+x_{n+1}^Tx_{n+1}$.
That identifies $x_{n+1}^Tx_{n+1}$ as the rank-one update for the Woodbury formula, or more simply, the Sherman-Morrison formula.

Comment: Thank you!

What would be the computational complexity if we consider $$ \beta' $$ without matrix inversion assuming we computed $$V_{n}^{-1} and X^{T}y$$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to translate your answer in terms of $$ V_{n+1}^{-1} $$